# Why use -1 when looping backwards in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's the code:

```
var john = ['John', 'Smith', 1990, 'teacher', false, 'blue'];

for (var i = john.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    console.log(john[i]);
}
```

I am trying to understand why use -1 in the declaration instead of using:

```
for(var i = john.length; i>-1; i--){
    console.log(john[i]);
}
```

Which to me makes more sense because the index i would have the value of the array which is 6 but since arrays starts with 0, it will not execute index 0 and therefore, for it to be executed, the condition has to be greater than -1.

Sorry I'm sort of new to programming.

Comment: The highest index of an array of length `3` is `2`: `0,1,2`.

Comment: Try running both versions of the code yourself and see what happens.

Comment: @FelixKling I am aware of that but why use john.length -1? I did run the code and there was an undefined value before it executes the array. Why is that so?

Comment: Because if `i = john.length`, then `i = 6` (in your example) and `john[6]` is `undefined` because the highest index is `5` (`john[5]` returns `'blue'`). Simple reproduction: `console.log([1,2,3][2]); console.log([1,2,3][3]);`.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you very much. Now that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration, `i` would be `john.length`, so the reference to `john[i]` would be past the end of the array. Array indexes go from 0 to `length - 1`.

Of course `i > -1` is just as good as `i >= 0` if you prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

For looping backwards, you might use a different pattern, which uses the [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)/[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) characteristic of a number in a condition.

This approach uses a check for truthiness and supports zero based indices of arrays.

```js
var john = ['John', 'Smith', 1990, 'teacher', false, 'blue'],
    i = john.length;

while (i--) {
    console.log(john[i]);
}
```